# Laravel 5 extend Elixir to include browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

My browserify workflow (from coffee to js, with `browserify-shim` and `coffeeify`) is like this:

I have 2 main files, `app.coffee` and `_app.coffee`, respectively for frontend and backend. Both files located in `resources/coffee/front` and `resources/coffee/back` (respectively). I'm trying to include `browserify` task in laravel elixir so the result file will be on `public/js/app.js` and `public/js/_app.js` and can be revision to the `build` folder later.

So far, I have tried to extend the elixir by creating a `browserify.js` file in elixir's node_modules `ingredients` folder. The content is:

```
var gulp                =   require('gulp');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var watchify        = require('watchify');
var source          =   require('vinyl-source-stream');
var logger          =   require('../../../gulp/util/bundleLogger');
var errors          =   require('../../../gulp/util/handleErrors');
var config          =   require('../../../gulp/config').browserify;

elixir.extend('browserify', function(callback) {
    var bundleQueue = config.bundleConfigs.length;
    var browserifyThis = function(bundleConfig) {
        var bundler = browserify({
            cache: {},
            packageCache: {},
            fullPaths: true,
            entries: bundleConfig.entries,
            extensions: config.extensions,
            debug: config.debug
        });

        var bundle = function() {
            logger.start(bundleConfig.outputName);

            return bundler
                .bundle()
                .on('error', errors)
                .pipe(source(bundleConfig.outputName))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(bundleConfig.dest))
                .on('end', finished);
        }

        if (global.isWatching) {
            bundler = watchify(bundler);
            bundler.on('update', bundle);
        }

        var finished = function() {
            logger.end(bundleConfig.outputName);
            if (bundleQueue) {
                bundleQueue--;
                if (bundleQueue === 0) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }

        return bundle();
    };

    config.bundleConfigs.forEach(browserifyThis);
});
```

Config for browserify is:

```
browserify: {
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.coffee'],
        watch: './resources/assets/coffee/{front,back}/**/*.coffee',
        bundleConfigs: [
        {
            entries: './resources/assets/coffee/front/app.coffee',
            dest: './public/js',
            outputName: 'app.js'
        },
        {
            entries: './resources/assets/coffee/back/app.coffee',
            dest:  './public/js',
            outputName: '_app.js'
        }]
    }
```

Then in my gulp elixir task, I do this:

```
var gulp        =   require('gulp');
var elixir  = require('laravel-elixir');

gulp.task('elixir', function() {
    return elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.sass('app.scss').browserify().version(['.public/css/app.css', './public/js/app.js', '.public/js/_app.js']);
    });
});
```

This does not work because the `callback` function is not included in elixir (originally it is gulp's). Even if it is, the elixir watch will not listen to my original `.coffee` files (I'm trying to watch the entire coffee file located in `resources/coffee/**/*.coffee`).

So what I have thought as a solution is to re-run the entire elixir procedure if the file changed, like:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    runSequence('coffeelint', 'browserify', 'elixir', 'images', 'watch');
});
```

and my `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.browserify.watch, ['coffeelint', 'default']);
    gulp.watch(config.images.src, ['images']);
});
```

But the error is that, it says that sass() function in elixir cannot be linked to browserify(). Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel elixir comes bundle with browserify so no need to do a require of browserify what you can do is

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify(['main.js'], 
                    'output directory',
                    'base-directory-if-different-from-public-folder');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine them, but you can run both.

```
//gulp.js in the root folder
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var browserify  = require('browserify');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass(['app.scss'], 'public/css');
});

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.browserify(['app.js'], 'public/js');
});
```